# how to get notified when any scheduled job fails?

Tags: apex, scheduled-job

For Scheduled job types listed below:

- Scheduled  Flow
- Reporting Notification
- Report Run
- Sitemap SEO Generation Job
- Sitemap SEO Incremental Job
- Autonomous Data Loader Job

Answer (score 3):

The platform doesn't provide this feature out of the box.

Some information about these processes may be available through the Event Monitoring add-on feature, such as [Asynchronous Report Runs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_asyncreportrun.htm). However, this feature is oriented towards compliance and security, not monitoring of failures.

The scheduled jobs you identify are heterogeneous. You can build fault paths into your Scheduled Flows, for example, to create appropriate error-handling solutions. Reporting Notifications are an OOTB process, and I'm not aware of a failure case that you would want to monitor.